# How to change "mpath" field name of materialized-path tree in typeorm?

Tags: typeorm

I hope you are well.

Is there any way to change the name of the "mpath" column that is automatically generated when using the materialized-path tree structure on typeorm?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.